# Creating right curve using css3

Tags: css

I want to create a curve as shown in below image using css.

[image]

I was trying something like this:

```
.test {
background-color: #1d637d;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-right: 0 solid #cccccc;
    border-radius: 0px 60px 60px 10px/10px 200px 200px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you this solution using two `<div>`s and `overflow: hidden;`:

https://jsfiddle.net/pf1no14x/

You can manipulate elements' sizes and positions to make it as desired.

And you still can place some content inside `.test` by creating another element either with `position: absolute;` or with `z-index` bigger than `.inner`'s.

Comment: can i use the same design for x number of lines without affecting the design?

Comment: how can i expend the height dynamically if i have x number of lines?

Comment: Sure you can. [Here's improved example](https://jsfiddle.net/pf1no14x/1/). If my answer is full and answers your question, you can upvote it and mark as accepted to show that the topic is closed and to say me thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome! You can also accept the answer (green tick) if there're no better answers.

Comment: can i use one more background along with curve? i have tried to implement yellow background similarly <div class="content1"> but it's not hiding the yellow background on right side curve?

Comment: the design similarly like this

Comment: if i have x number of lines, the alignment is not proper

Comment: In this case the layout would be totally different.

Comment: pls give your suggestion on this.

Comment: When you have to place the content inside circle block and set the height and `overflow: hidden`.